# Invalid type parameter class str, valid types class dict

Tags: python-3.x, boto3

So I'm attempting to sync Dynamodb tables using put_item. But I've run into an issue.

```
Invalid type for parameter Item.Artist, value: No One You Know, type: <class 'str'>, valid types: <class 'dict'>
```

From reading the documentation it looks like when using put_item it requires a dict so essentially something like this:

```
'{'Artist': {'S': 'No One You Know'},'SongTitle': {'S': 'Call Me Today'}}'
```

In order to add it correctly.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import boto3
source = boto3.resource('dynamodb', 'us-east-1')
dest = boto3.client('dynamodb', 'us-west-2')

def sync(source, dest):
     table = source.Table("myMusic")
     scan_kwargs = {
         'ProjectionExpression': "Artist, SongTitle"
     }
     done = False
     start_key = None
     while not done:
         if start_key:
             scan_kwargs['ExclusiveStartKey'] = start_key
         response = table.scan(**scan_kwargs)
         for item in response['Items']:
             dest.put_item(TableName="myMusic", Item=item)
             #print(item)
         start_key = response.get('LastEvaluatedKey', None)
         done = start_key is None


sync(source, dest)
```

So if I uncomment the print statement I get:

```
{'Artist': 'No One You Know', 'SongTitle': 'Call Me Today'}
```

Is there any way to sanitize the output or add the additional required 'S' or am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At some stage in your code, you will have  `item = {'Artist': 'No One You Know', 'SongTitle': 'Call Me Today'}`
which you are saying is printed when you uncomment the print statement.

Use the following snippet of code:

```
newItem = { 'Artist': {}, 'SongTitle': {} }

newItem['Artist']['S'] = item['Artist']
newItem['SongTitle']['S'] = item['SongTitle']
```

So whole code becomes:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import boto3
source = boto3.resource('dynamodb', 'us-east-1')
dest = boto3.client('dynamodb', 'us-west-2')

def sync(source, dest):
     table = source.Table("myMusic")
     scan_kwargs = {
         'ProjectionExpression': "Artist, SongTitle"
     }
     done = False
     start_key = None
     while not done:
         if start_key:
             scan_kwargs['ExclusiveStartKey'] = start_key
         response = table.scan(**scan_kwargs)
         for item in response['Items']:
             
#######################  SNIPPET  #######################  
             newItem = { 'Artist': {}, 'SongTitle': {} }

             newItem['Artist']['S'] = item['Artist']
             newItem['SongTitle']['S'] = item['SongTitle']
#######################  SNIPPET  #######################  

             dest.put_item(TableName="myMusic", Item=newItem)
             #print(item)
         start_key = response.get('LastEvaluatedKey', None)
         done = start_key is None
```

Comment: Thank You! That worked. I wasn't sure if I should be using boto3.resource as the dest as well but that worked very well. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem while testing my Lambda function using RestAPI. I was using curl to test. I managed to comply with put_item syntax without modifying my function code by using --data-raw option in curl.

Below is for Windows curl hence I need to use double to enclose the data instead of single quote and escape character \ in order to use double quote in my data.

> curl api_url --data-raw "{\"uId\": {\"S\": \"4\"}, \"Add\": {\"SS\":
> [\"address 1\",\"address 2\"]}, \"email\": {\"S\":
> \"emailId@domain.com\"}, \"mob\": {\"N\": \"6512345678\"}, \"name\":
> {\"S\": \"Vijaya R\"}}"

Probably for non-Windows this should work (not tested).

> curl api_url --data-raw '{"uId": {"S": "4"}, "Add": {"SS":
> ["address 1","address 2"]}, "email": {"S":
> "emailId@domain.com"}, "mob": {"N": "6512345678"}, "name":
> {"S": "Vijaya R"}}'