# DynamoDB Query cli "Parameter validation failed"

Tags: amazon-web-services, parameters, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I'm using the AWS CLI to make a dynamoDB query that includes `key-condition-expression` and `expression-attribute-names` and I keep getting invalid errors:

```
Invalid type for parameter ExpressionAttributeNames.:taskName, value: OrderedDict([(u'S', u'taskOne')]), type: <class 'collections.OrderedDict'>, valid types: <type 'basestring'>
Invalid type for parameter ExpressionAttributeNames.#status, value: OrderedDict([(u'S', u'status')]), type: <class 'collections.OrderedDict'>, valid types: <type 'basestring'>
Invalid type for parameter ExpressionAttributeNames.:status, value: OrderedDict([(u'S', u'success')]), type: <class 'collections.OrderedDict'>, valid types: <type 'basestring'>
```

I've looked at previous questions such as [dynamodb-get-item-boto3-parameter-validation-failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72175440/dynamodb-get-item-boto3-parameter-validation-failed) and [invalid-type-parameter-class-str-valid-types-class-dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67287259/invalid-type-parameter-class-str-valid-types-class-dict) but I'm not seeing what I'm doing wrong.

Dynamo calls require the attribute datatype, which I have included, but I think that's what is causing the error. Removing the datatype causes another expected error.

Heres my call:

```
aws dynamodb query \
    --table-name myTable \
    --key-condition-expression "taskName = :taskName AND #status = :status" \
    --expression-attribute-names '{":taskName":{"S":"taskOne"},"#status":{"S":"status"},":status":{"S":"success"}}'
```

UPDATE:
When I remove the datatype: `"S"`, I get this error:

> Error parsing parameter '--expression-attribute-names': Invalid JSON: No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: Could you try it without the {"s" ...} and just the String?
 `--expression-attribute-names '{":taskName":"taskOne","#status":"status",":status":success"}'`

Or what is the the other unexpected error if you try it just with the strings?

Comment: I added the error , apologies for the ommission.

Answer (score 3):

You're mixing attribute names and values under attribute names. You need both https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ExpressionAttributeValues.html
Names are a pure string, and values are an object as you defined with the `"S`" as type. But both are defined separately

Try this

```
aws dynamodb query \
    --table-name myTable \
    --key-condition-expression "#taskName = :taskName AND #status = :status" \
    --expression-attribute-names '{"#taskName": "taskName","#status": "status"}'
    --expression-attribute-values '{":taskName":{"S":"taskOne"},":status":{"S":"success"}}'
```